# Запускаю скрипт для удаления лог-файлов из базы Postgresql, ошибка с модулями

Tags: linux

Запускаю скрипт для удаления лог-файлов из базы *Postgresql*, ошибка с модулями. Обновил *CPAN-perl*, но все-равно выдает ошибку. Подскажите причину, что еще нужно поставить.

Прилагаю лог-ошибки:

```
sudo/home/projects/system_sms_partition/delete_old_partitions.sh/home/projects/system_sms_partition/delete_old_partitions.conf delete
Can't locate Data/GUID.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/projects/SHARED_API /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /home/projects/SHARED_API/db.pm line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/projects/SHARED_API/db.pm line 12.
Compilation failed in require at /home/projects/system_sms_partition/delete_old_partitions.sh line 75.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/projects/system_sms_partition/delete_old_partitions.sh line 75
```

Comment: А что означает "обновил CPAN-perl". Судя по ошибке у вас не установлен модуль `Data::GUID` установите его с CPAN

Comment: установил GUID, все равно он жалуется что его нет

Comment: sudo /home/projects/system_sms_partition/delete_old_partitions.sh /home/projects/system_sms_partition/delete_old_partitions.conf delete
Can't locate Data/GUID.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/projects/SHARED_API /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /home/projects/SHARED_API/db.pm line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/projects/SHARED_API/db.pm line 12.

Comment: Вы посмотрите куда он ставится и убедитесь что он там есть . ставили же в cpan командой `install Data::GUID` ?

Comment: да install Data::GUID

Comment: И делали это под рутом ? как то странно что бы он не находился после установки. Надо понять куда же он его поставил, что потом не находит. Обычно все ставится в какой нибудь из подкаталогов с именем vendor_perl. Но у вас в @INC почему то нет этого пути. Может ваш скрипт сам модифицирует @INC и делает это как то неудачно. Попробуйте выполнить из командной строки `perl -e 'use Data::GUID;'` интересно он ту же ошибку выдаст или нет

Comment: Посмотрите еще `perl -V` он пишет какую @INC он использует по умолчанию. И если там есть каталоги vendor_perl, а при запуске скрипта в сообщениях об ошибке их нет, значит действительно скрипт портит ...

Comment: использует Debian-овский @INC

Comment: DEBPKG:debian/mod_paths - Tweak @INC ordering for Debian

Comment: DEBPKG:debian/no_packlist_perllocal - Don't install .packlist or perllocal.pod for perl or vendor
 DEBPKG:debian/instmodsh_doc - Debian policy doesn't install .packlist files for core or vendor.

Comment: Просто поищите GUID.pm для начала в /usr/lib/perl5, посмотрите куда все таки cpan его поставил и есть ли этот путь в текущем INC.

Comment: GUID.pm нет в директории, но меня смущает, что там есть файл UUID.pm, может с этим проблема?

Comment: Кстати, в дебиане есть свой пакет с этой библиотекой https://packages.debian.org/sid/perl/libdata-guid-perl может стоит поставить его через установщик дебиана

Comment: а старые пакеты удалить?

Comment: С этим боюсь проблемы возникнут. cpan удалять не умеет, а руками муторно. Так что так ставьте, надеюсь они конфликтовать не будут. Но раз пакет и так не находится думаю не страшно

Comment: К сожалению не получается установить пакет dpkg: error processing 
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libdata-guid-perl

Comment: Судя по ошибке от установленного с cpan пакета устновилась документация. и она мешает deb пакету. посмотрите в /usr/share/man/man3 удалите файлы от пакета, по названию понятно должно быть. И надо бы поискать логи установки, они наверняка куда то пишутся и там должно быть сказано какие файлы пересекаются. Так же посмотрите может у aptget или чем вы там ставите пакет есть игнорировние существования файлов